# How to disable or hide a link depending on users role?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a web application (JSP, Javascript and Java servlets) that starts with a login page, and forwards to a main page with a navigation menu from where functional pages can be accessed.

Users can have several roles and several access rights; I want to hide or disable the links in the navigation menu, if the user has not the proper role (of course not only set the color of the link).

I tried invoking the servlet via javascript and setting the hidden attribute of the link in the onreadystatechange function:

```
window.location.assign("main.jsp");
document.getElementById("menuitem1").hidden = true;
```

but after location.assign() the javascript method does not continue.

If I first call .hidden = true and then location.assign, the menu item is not known, as I am still in the login page.

From the servlet I can forward to the main page, but I don´t find how then to manage the attributes of the link.

I could write a separate main page for each user role, but then I would have to extend each of these pages when a new menu item is added. I would prefer (if possible) to forward to a common main page and then something like: if (condition) {menuitem.hidden=true;}

How can I implement that?

Comment: The way to do it is have the server control what is there.

Comment: Once you change the page the page you're on goes away, kind of by definition. If you have stuff on pages then run the JS on *that page*, not the page from which you're coming.

Comment: Do that on server side ..not on client side.

Comment: Hi epascarello and Swati,

I did not understand your advise. Of course the server detects the user role. But how can I set the attributes of the href from server side?

Best regards
Gerhard